# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (create-build-target-link) on project flink-dist_2.12

Tags: maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run `./mvnw clean package -DskipTests`  command on Flink-1.16.0 source code and build is getting failed on flink-dist module with following error. Please let me know if there is any way to fix it.

I am using JDK 11.0.19 with Maven : 3.3.9

```
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] Total time: 20:28 min
>     [INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-10T08:32:16+00:00
>     [INFO] Final Memory: 352M/1228M
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec
> (create-build-target-link) on project flink-dist_2.12: Command
> execution failed. Stream closed -> [Help 1]
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>     [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>     [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :flink-dist_2.12
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the version of Maven you're using, the platform/version where you're building, and the actual error of the failure. That is all important information for figuring out why it failed.

Comment: +1 for @kkrugler his comment, most likely you're using a Maven version newer then 3.2.5 or a Java version newer then 11, which doesn't work for Flink 1.16.0

Comment: Added : I am using JDK 11 with Maven : 3.3.9

Comment: So what happens if you use Maven 3.2.5 (or older)?

Comment: I randomly tried with maven 3.8.5 and it build successfully. Not sure why but Thanks martijn-visser , @kkrugler for the suggestions